# Can't use class constructor argument in Python

Tags: python, class, arguments, init

I can't get what I'm doing wrong here. I'm defining a class with the following code:

```
import sqlite3 as lite
import sys 
import os.path
class database:
    def __init__(self,dbfname):
       if os.path.isfile(dbfname):
            self.con = lite.connect(dbfname)
       else:
            self.con = self.createDBfile(dbfname)
    #Other methods...
```

Then, when I try to make an instance of the class

```
base = database("mydb.db")
```

I get an error saying that there is no "global" variable named *dbfname* .

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "testdb.py", line 67, in <module>
base = database("mydb.db")
File "testdb.py", line 13, in __init__
self.con = self.createDBfile(dbfname)
File "testdb.py", line 15, in createDBfile
if os.path.isfile(dbfname):
NameError: global name 'dbfname' is not defined
```

What would be the correct way to use the argument variable dbfname ?

Comment: Is that literally your code...? Because it's broken and/or badly formatted. Please double check what you pasted here, and especially its indentation.

Comment: I fixed a duplication of the line "class database:" Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code looks fine. The error isn't in the code you posted though; it's in `testdb.py` on line 15 in the `createDBfile()` method (not in the `__init__()`).

How do I know this? Well, lets carefully look at the traceback Python gives us:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testdb.py", line 67, in <module>
    base = database("mydb.db")
  File "testdb.py", line 13, in __init__
    self.con = self.createDBfile(dbfname)
  File "testdb.py", line 15, in createDBfile
    if os.path.isfile(dbfname):
NameError: global name 'dbfname' is not defined
```

Like the first line says, the most recent call is **last**. So you read a traceback from down to up (and not from up to down).

The very last line is the actual error, but just before that is:

```
  File "testdb.py", line 15, in createDBfile
    if os.path.isfile(dbfname):
```

So it says that in the file `testdb.py`, on line 15, in the method `createDBfile()` an error occurred. Python also prints out the contents of this line 15.

Above that is the call to the `createDBfile()` method in your `__init__()` function, and above that the call to the `__init__()` function (by creating the class instance).

You didn't post the contents of this `createDBfile()` method, so I can't tell you where exactly the error is. I suspect you did something wrong with the function arguments (perhaps as simple as a typo?)

Comment: You where absolutely right, thanks!  I had used a different name for the filename variable in the definition of the createDBfile method, and then forgot about it!